Localhost keep reloading
I have a PHP Phalcon setup on Ubuntu with the following versions:

PHP = 7.4.33
Phalcon = 4.0
Phalcon Dev Tools = 4.2
Ubuntu = 20.02
Server = Apache 2

The issue I am facing is that my localhost responds very slowly. When I reload my Phalcon project, it takes up to 10 minutes to respond. I have tried various solutions suggested by others, but nothing has worked so far. Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a solution?
Here is my server information
bilal@bilal:~$  sudo systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-07-04 16:12:17 PKT; 35min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 63016 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 63020 (apache2)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 18927)
     Memory: 16.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─63020 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─63021 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─63022 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─63023 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─63024 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─63025 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

جولائی 04 16:12:17 bilal systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
جولائی 04 16:12:17 bilal systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.


PHP 7.4.33 is horribly outdated, Ubuntu 20.02 (which might be 20.04?) is also not the latest one. Did you check whether you're facing a bug that is resolved in more current versions?

i cant switch to latest one as my code supportes 7.4. The same code works fine on my friends machine with the same configration except ubantu. He got ubantu 18 older then mine. Can you tell me anything which can bost up localhost responses and apache2

As you haven't shared a single line of code, it's impossible to tell you how to speed it up

there is no issue in the code. If code is the issue then every one else face the issue. but it works on every machine exceopt mine

but if you want to see any specfic thing from configration i can share you that

Good to know. Then there's nothing you can do about this: the code is fine, Phalcon, Ubuntu, and Apacha are also working fine for thousands of other people. Sarcasm off: if you don't let others check what your application makes different than others, it's impossible for them to tell you where you could start optimizing. Additionally, PHP 8 has huge performance improvements

I agree with you, PHP 8 is superb. However, in my case, I have to stay with the older version. I suspect there might be an Apache2 configuration issue. Whenever I reload my localhost, all other requests respond well except the main localhost request, which remains pending for minutes.

visit the below link to see request time
https://i.postimg.cc/vmbbj0VS/Screenshot-1.png

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, and share more details about your application. As far as I read the screenshot, it does not tell anything new

Are you loading your app in its own domain (i.e. http://app.local) or as a subdirectory (i.e. http://localhost/app)? Are you creating an MVC or Micro App?
